# How do you change source in a web audio context

Tags: html, api, google-chrome, audio, web-audio-api

I'm making a game that changes some of it's object depending on what music is playing. After each song has ended I want my audio context to load in a new source and analyze that. However whenever I tried to do that I've gotten the error that an audio object or buffer can't be called twice.

After some researching I learned that `ctx.createMediaElementSource(MyHTML5AudioEl)` lets you create a sourceNode that takes the source from a HTML5  object. With this I was able to loop through different song.

However for my game I need to play/analyze a 30 seconds "remote url" that comes out of the Spotify API. I might be wrong but `ctx.createMediaElementSource(MyHTML5AudioEl)`does not allow you to analyze a source that is on a remote site.

Also the game needs to work on Mobile Chrome, which `createMediaElementSource(MyHTML5AudioEl)` does not seem to work on.

I might be on the completely wrong path here but my main question is:
How can I switch remote songs urls in web audio api. With it being compatible with mobile chrome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as you found out, you can't set the buffer again for an `AudioBufferSource`.  The solution is to create a new one.  `AudioBufferSource`s are intended to be light-weight objects that you can easily create and use.

Second, in Chrome 42 and newer, `createMediaElementSource` requires appropriate CORS access so you have to make sure the remote url sends the appropriate headers and you set the `crossOrigin` attribute appropriately.

Finally, Mobile Chrome currently does not pass the data from an audio element through `createMediaElementSource`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your awnsers, with the information you provided I came up with an appropiate solution!